# Send multiple Fluxes with different types in one response

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

If I have code like so:

```
data class Response(
  val a: String,
  val b: List<String>,
  val c: Int,
)

fun buildResponse(): Response {
  val a: Mono<String> = getA()
  val b: Flux<String> = getB()
  val c: Mono<Int> = getC()

  return Response(
    a = a.blockOptional().orElseThrow(),
    b = b.collectList().blockOptional().orElseThrow(),
    c = c.blockOptional().orElseThrow(),
  )
}
```

Is there a way to reactively return a `Mono<Response>` instead of blocking and returning the actual `Response`?

Comment: Have you looked at the `zip` operators?

Comment: no, can you type a short example?

Comment: Sure, see my answer. (A kotlin language tag may have also helped get a quicker answer here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - have a look at the `Mono.zip` operator, which will allow you to combine several publishers into a single Mono. The basic `Mono.zip` variants just return a tuple, but you can also specify your own class (`Response` in this case) as so:

```
return Mono.zip(
        Function { eles: Array<Any> ->
            Response(eles[0] as String,
                    eles[1] as List<String>,
                    eles[2] as Int)
        },
        a, b.collectList(), c)
```